# Easiest way to get only part of a string in bash

Tags: bash

I like to listen to sky.fm and I use curl to query media information

What I use right now is:

```
curl -s curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json | grep now_playing
```

This returns:

```
"now_playing":"Cody Simpson - On My Mind"
```

What I would like to have is:

```
Cody Simpson - On My Mind
```

Maybe even better, put the artist and title in separate variables.

```
artist: Cody Simpson
title: On My mind
```

### Solution

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json | grep -Po '(?<=now_playing":")[^"]+'`
artist=$(echo $a | awk -F' - ' '{print $1}')
title=$(echo $a | awk -F' - ' '{print $2}')
echo $artist
echo $title
```

Comment: I have added a method for putting artist and title into separate variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using cut.

```
curl -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json | \
   grep 'now_playing' | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/"//g'
```

The cut command helps you select fields. The fields are defined by a delimiter, in this case `':'`. The `-d` option specifies the delimiter, the `-f` option specifies the fields we want to select.

The sed part is simply to remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks that gets the job done :). In 10 minutes I will accept your answer. Could you please explain the cut command a little better?

Comment: Sure. The cut command helps you select fields. The fields are defined by delimiters, in this case ':'. The -d option specifies the delimiter, the -f option specifies the fields we want to select.

Comment: And that sed part is to remove the quotes? Could you please update that in your answer? I would like to have this as a reference.

Comment: I made an update to my question? My final question is how to put the artist and title in variables?

Comment: A smarter thing to do would be to set the delimiter to `"` and grab the fourth field `grep 'now_playing' | cut -d'"' -f4` this drops the need for `sed`. Better yet see my answer on how to use positive lookbehind with `grep` so `cut` isn't needed either.

Comment: @sudo_O: That wouldn't work if there are quotes in the song title. e.g. `"now_playing":"how to say \"goodbye\""`. Then again, a colon would also mess with things. I think to get a foolproof command you'd have to spend a bit more time.

Comment: You just said we should set the delimiter to `"` because it would drop the need for sed :p

Comment: I know, my point is neither solution would be correct for that cases :L

Comment: I see, right. It would take some time to get a foolproof command.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach if you have `GNU grep`:

```
curl ... | grep -Po '(?<=now_playing":")[^"]+'
Cody Simpson - On My Mind
```

*Where `curl ...` is replaced by your actual `curl` command.*

**Edit:**

I'd go with `awk` for your second request:

```
curl ... | awk -F'"' '{split($4,a," - ");print "artist:",a[1],"\ntitle:",a[2]}'
artist: Cody Simpson 
title: On My Mind
```

To store in shell variables:

```
artist=$(curl ... | awk -F'"' '{split($4,a," - ");print a[1]}')

echo "$artist"
Cody Simpson

title=$(curl ... | awk -F'"' '{split($4,a," - ");print a[2]}')

echo "$title"
On My Mind
```

Comment: That way I have to do curl to an URL twice. Is it also possible to store the results in a variable only do CURL once? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

with sed:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json' | \ 
        sed '/now_playing/s/^\"now_playing\":"\(.*\)"$/\1/'
```

with grep, cut and tr:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json' | \ 
        grep now_playing | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"'
```

with awk:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json' | \
        awk -F':' '/now_playing/ {gsub(/"/,""); print $2 }'
```